# Why isnt my django heroku admin not working

Tags: django, heroku

I created a heroku superuser using the "heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser" command but when i try to log in to my admin pannel in heroku it tells me i am putting wrong login credentials even though they are correct.

Comment: Do you have caps lock on? [so] isn't here for password recovery

Comment: no, caps lock off..i am using email and password for my login details, and i am putting in correct login info

Comment: Educated guess: are you using SQLite?

Comment: Am using postgress..but it seems like there may be issues on linking the database to heroku

Comment: local superuser works just fine but herokusuperuser has failed to login

Comment: Are you _entirely sure_ you're using PostgreSQL? Do you see data actually being saved to your database?

Comment: No worries, i have finally solved it, the issue was i hadnt added is_staff property to superusers yet heroku requires admins to have it